# How do I place my main method into a try catch block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, program-entry-point

I'm making a game and my try and catch blocks work inside the methods, but one of the criteria for my assignment is to place the main method into a try catch block as well. But whenever I wrap my main method in a `try{ }` block, it gives me a compile error: Illegal start of type. I've looked this up and I've concluded I need to place the try block into its own method, but when I do this I get an Illegal start of expression. How exactly do I place my main method into a try catch block?

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Board board = new Board();
    board.display();
    board.validate();
}
```

When I tried wrapping it in a try catch block (Illegal start type)

```
try{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Board board = new Board();
        board.display();
        board.validate();
    }
}
```

And when I tried to place it inside a method (Illegal start of expression)

```
    public void tryCatch(){

       try{
           public static void main(String[] args){
               Board board = new Board();
               board.display();
               board.validate();
           }        
      }
  }
```

Comment: "but one of the criteria for my assignment is to place the main method into a try catch block aswell." please reread your criteria. What you are asking is impossible in Java (at least if it means to declare method directly inside try-catch block). What you can do is let your method rethrow exception (by adding `throws` clausule). You may also be asked to *invoke* your method inside some try-catch blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't, you wrap the contents of your `main` method in the `try-catch` or have the `main` method re-throw the resulting exception

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        Board board = new Board();
        board.display();
        board.validate();
    } catch (... exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Take a closer look at [Catching and Handling Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) for more details

Comment: *Unrelated* but I'm curious to know that why did you add answer as a community wiki ?

Comment: @TAsk Frankly, the question is (IMHO) low quality, it's a simple misunderstanding of the language syntax which could be fixed by reading any number of tutorials. Personally, I think the question should closed as such, but I hate seeing new developers struggling with these types of concepts.  They own reason I added an answer was because it wouldn't work as a comment, so it becomes an "extended" comment instead. I've also not waffled on about language specifics and why the OP's attempt wouldn't work, so it's now open should any one to extend the answer to include them ;)

Comment: @TAsk And do I really need reputation from such a simple question? (No offense to anybody intended)

Comment: Not at all :) I was just curious to know whether it's good to add answers as community wiki in such cases or not.

Comment: @TAsk Some people don't like these types of questions to be answered, as they don't see the value in them (ie the OP should do more research or investigation or what ever), so I post them as wiki's. Part of my intention is to also reduce the number of other people who might try and answer these types of questions (for rep) as this encourages people to continue to post low quality questions without doing due diligence. But again, that's just my opinion. I get a lot of value of out other peoples answer to problems I face, so this is a little give back/paying it forward ;)

Comment: Sorry if you find the 'quality' of my question to be low, but I'm sure it will help out others in the future who are also new. I had been looking at tutorials but most seemed to gloss over the idea that you just put the contents of the main method into the try{}catch{} block rather than the entire method. Sometimes your brain can just be fried after a long day of coding and a lot of online tutorials miss these minute details. Regardless thanks for answering my question.

Comment: @Alkarin Don't take offense, as I said, this is why I answered it as a wiki answer, helps you, stops other people from ranting ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Caught Exception " + e);
        }
    });


    throw new Exception("a serious problem occured");
}
```

and here is the output

> Caught Exception java.lang.Exception: a serious problem occured